# angular2.x strongly typed parameter that is a component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am writing a function who's first parameter is an angular2 component. I want to strongly type is so that i can only pass in classes that use ng2's @Component decorator. I looked at some libraries like NgbModal's 'open' function which has a first parameter of a component but it was typed to "any" in the interface.

thank you

Comment: A component is nothing but a class in typescript. You can try setting the type as name of the class like this function (someName: ComponentClassName) { }

Comment: Thank you! Is there a more Generic way? with that implementation I would only be able to pass in one type of component class.

Comment: you can try using generics. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-types